# r verbose output on when converting factor to ordered

Tags: r, dataframe

I am getting a lot of unnecessary verbose output when I run the ordered function over my data frame for a column that I have defined as a factor.

My R code:

```
# Convert column to factor
data_3_base$soc <- as.factor(data_3_base$soc)

# Set the order of the Soc from 0 - 4
ordered(data_3_base$soc, levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

How do I stop the output?

Comment: Your first code means "take the `soc` variable of `data_3_base`, convert it to factor, and assign the output of that back the same `soc` column. ie change soc to factor." Your second code, since it has no assignment, means, "take the `soc` variable, change it to an ordered factor, and print the whole result, but don't save it anywhere."

Answer (score 2):

It is not an in-place operator; you simply need to assign it:

```
data_3_base$soc <-ordered(data_3_base$soc, levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4"))
```